# $\tan(\theta) = x/2 \Rightarrow \sin(\theta) = x/\sqrt{4+x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I do not see why if we have $\tan(\theta) = x/2$ we know that $\sin(\theta) = x/\sqrt{4+x^2}$

Can someone please explain that to me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Draw the right-angled triangle, then you can get intuition.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{O}{A}\implies O=x, A = 2\implies H = \sqrt{4+x^2}$$
$$\implies \sin(\theta)=\frac{O}{H}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}$$

Edit: As others have pointed out, I should really make explicit the assumption that $\tfrac{-\pi}{2}< \theta < \tfrac{\pi }{2}$. This assumption seems to be standard when dealing with trigonometric substitutions, which is where you may more commonly have to make such inferences, but should be stated regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove the equality you're after, because it is false.

---

We have, in general,
$$
\sin^2\theta=\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta}=
\frac{\sin^2\theta/\cos^2\theta}{(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)/\cos^2\theta}=
\frac{\tan^2\theta}{\tan^2\theta+1}
$$
In your case,
$$
\sin^2\theta=\frac{x^2/4}{(x^2/4)+1}=\frac{x^2}{x^2+4}
$$
This entails
$$
\lvert\sin\theta\rvert=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}
$$
which is the most you can say.

For instance, if $\theta=3\pi/4$, we have
$$
\tan\frac{3\pi}{4}=-1
$$
so $x=-2$; on the other hand,
$$
\sin\frac{3\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
whereas
$$
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{4+4}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\forall t\in\mathbb R \; \frac{1}{ 1+(\tan(t))^2}=1-(\sin(t))^2$$

Answer (score 0):

In the right angled triangle the side opposite $\theta $ is $x$ and adjecent side is $2$ and so  hypotenuse is$\sqrt{4+x^2}$ and so $\sin \theta= \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}. $  If $\sin \theta $ is given then we get back $ \tan \theta = \dfrac{x}{2}.$

If $\sin \theta $ admits both signs due to $\pm$ before radical sign then  $\tan \theta $ also admits the same two. You should check other quadrant, other than first quadrant, for the two solutions obtained.